# How do I capture user input as a variable, perform calculations, then display the result in another control without using MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have written a console application using C++ that performs a number of tasks, as per the following menu.
0 – to quit system
1 – Show message
2 – Cube a number
3 – Convert to Fahrenheit
4 – Test an array
5 – Add many integers
6 – Get seven Lotto numbers for System 7
7 – Read historical data file (file name is s.csv)
8 – Display historical results
9 – Display frequency counts

The current project is to turn this into a Windows application using MS Visual C++ Express. I must use this IDE. Note that the Express(free) version does not include the Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC). Almost all of the information that I have found relates to using MFC.

I’ve started to write a solution as a Windows Forms Application.

So far I have a menu on the form that will display and clear a message and close the Window.

I have added text boxes and labels to the form however I don’t know how to capture user input as a variable, perform calculations on the input then display the result in another control.

I will probably use separate dialog boxes for each menu option in the final solution. However for now I would just like to get a simple calculation to work.

This is my first post. All guidance and answers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a **`ValueChanged` event handler** to the text box. You may need to set a  global var that is the desired number, so the constructor (or whatever) of the other form can change the text of a label, as I don't think you can change it from a different form.